# Unable to run spring boot test cases with Neo4j database when offline or neo4j server is down

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In my Spring-Boot application using Neo4j database and connecting it with org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver

I have mocked the data in test cases and its working properly when connected to database. But test cases getting failed when offline or Neo4j server is down, showing following exception.

```
springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Neo4j Session for transaction; nested exception is org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to process request: Network is unreachable
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:102)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ChannelFactory.connect(ChannelFactory.java:64)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ChannelFactory.create(ChannelFactory.java:41)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.start(SocketClient.java:124)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.startSocketClient(SocketConnection.java:92)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.<init>(SocketConnection.java:67)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnector.createConnection(SocketConnector.java:77)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:50)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool$ConnectionSupplier.get(SocketConnectionPool.java:204)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool$ConnectionSupplier.get(SocketConnectionPool.java:186)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.BlockingPooledConnectionQueue.acquire(BlockingPooledConnectionQueue.java:96)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SocketConnectionPool.java:137)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool.acquire(SocketConnectionPool.java:76)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DirectConnectionProvider.acquireConnection(DirectConnectionProvider.java:45)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.acquireConnection(NetworkSession.java:340)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.beginTransaction(NetworkSession.java:288)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.NetworkSession.beginTransaction(NetworkSession.java:175)
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.nativeTransaction(BoltDriver.java:159)
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.newTransaction(BoltDriver.java:113)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:71)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:57)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate.beginTransaction(TransactionsDelegate.java:36)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.beginTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:463)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doBegin(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:176)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
at io.marchex.api.service.FeatureService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3008b8d0.getTagFeaturesByAccountId(<generated>)
at io.marchex.api.resource.FeatureResource.getTagFeaturesByAccountId(FeatureResource.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:160)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
at io.marchex.FeatureResourceTest.testGetTagFeaturesByAccountId_AccounNotExists(FeatureResourceTest.java:85)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to test against an embedded / discardable instance, right?

You could override the `application.properties` for test without any specification of the URI property (`spring.data.neo4j.uri`) to let the tests use temporary data storage with an embedded instance.

In this case you have to provide the database in your dependencies.
e.g. for Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```